# Trying to make a REST GET call in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to make a GET REST call in Node.js.When I use postman to perform the GET I get a proper JSON output but in node.js code I get output in the form of some special character.

my GET code looks like this :

```
    var http = require('http');
    var requestrespone = require("request");
    var config = require('../config/config.js');
    var jsonFile = require('jsonfile');
    var jsonFile=require('../json_input/jsoninput.json');
    var cheerio =require('cheerio');
    var express=require('express');
var getOptions=
{
    host : config.host,
    method : config.get,
    path: config.getpath,
    headers :config.getheader

};


    console.info('Options prepared:');
        console.info(getOptions);
        console.info('Do the GET call');

        var reqGet = http.request(getOptions, function(res) {
            console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
            // uncomment it for header details
        //  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


            res.on('data', function(d) {
                console.info('GET result after GET:\n');

                console.log(d);
                console.info('\n\nCall completed');
            });

        });

        reqGet.end();
        reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
```

My output looks like this :

```
<Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 91 41 4f e3 30 10 85 ff 8b cf a6 38 89
13 db bd 22 a8 2a b1 a5 6a 17 71 40 3d 4c e2 69 e5 25 b5 8d eb 14 15 c4 7f df ..
. >
```

Please tell me what wrong am i doing ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to string. You get `Buffer` type.
Assuming `data` is your result and has `Buffer` type

`data.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

I have always found using [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) the best way to do POST/GET calls through node programs. the callbacks are also pretty easy and configurable.

```
var request = require('superagent');
var config = require('./appConfig.json');

var dataToSend = {
    authentication: 'any_auth_if_required',
    data: 'data_to_post'
};

makePostCall(dataToSend);

makeGetCall(dataToSend);

function makePostCall(dataToSend){
    request.post('URL_FOR_POST_CALL')
    .send(dataToSend)
    .set('Cross-Domain', 'true')
    .set('Cache', 'false')
    .accept('json')
    .end(function(err, res) {
        if (res && res.body) {
            console.log(res.body);
            //process.exit();
        }
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

function makeGetCall(dataToSend){
    request.get('URL_FOR_GET_CALL')
    .query(dataToSend)
    .set('Cross-Domain', 'true')
    .set('Cache', 'false')
    .accept('json')
    .end(function(err, res) {
        if (res && res.body) {
            console.log(res.body);
            //process.exit();
        }
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather Native Node.js Approach:

```
var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "port": "80",
  "path": "/api/data/",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ name: 'testName1', info: 'testInfoData' }));
req.end();
```

Using popular `Request` Library:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/things',
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: { name: 'testName1', info: 'testInfoData' },
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```